# Plot Multiple and Separate Charts from Pivot Tables

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a csv file containing the following info:

```
Time,   Type,   Gender,   Hair,    Eyes    Age      
1:00,   Adult,  Male,     Brown,   Green,  33
1:10,   Adult,  Female,   Blonde,  Green,  67
1:15,   Child,  Female,   Red,     Brown,  13
1:20,   Child,  Male,     Blonde,  Blue,   5
1:50,   Child,  Male,     Red,     Brown,  17
2:00,   Adult,  Female,   Brown,   Blue,   42
```

I create a dataFrame from this file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(myCSV)
```

and then I create separate pivot tables from that dataFrame:

```
pivot1 = df.pivot_table(index=['Time'], columns=['Gender', 'Eyes'], values=['Age'])

pivot2 = df.pivot_table(index=['Time'], columns=['Hair'])

pivot3 = df.pivot_table(index=['Time'], columns=['Type'], values=['Age'])
```

I would like to `plt.plot()` all pivot tables (and ideally many more) as **separate** charts, but I am running into dead ends as to how to do this when calling `plt.show()`.

I'll spare the reader examples of my myriad attempts, in order to keep the question clean and concise.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Put them in a for loop and plt.show() in each iteration?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to show multiple plots at the same time. There are many ways of doing this, but I would recommend using subplots. I simulated 1000 data points representative of the data sample you provided. The pivot_table commands in your post do not result in meaningful dataframes, so it's not very clear what you are trying to plot. Regardless, here is an example of how to use subplots to show many plots on one figure. You can increase the nrows or ncols parameters to show as many plots as you would like on a single figure. Hopefully this is able to answer your question.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#generate data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Time': pd.date_range(start='1-1-2021 13:00:00', periods=1000, freq='600s'), 
    'Type': np.random.choice(['Adult', 'Child'], 1000), 
    'Gender': np.random.choice(['M','F'], 1000),
    'Hair': np.random.choice(['Brown','Blonde','Red','Black'], 1000),
    'Eyes': np.random.choice(['Green','Brown','Blue','Brown'], 1000),
    'Age': np.random.randint(18, 64, 1000)
})

#make some groupings for bar charts
plot_1 = df.groupby(['Gender','Hair'], as_index=False).Age.mean()
plot_2 = df.groupby('Type').Gender.size()
plot_3 = df.groupby('Type').Age.mean()

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=1, figsize=(18,8)) #define fig/axes
axes = axes.flatten() #make axes a 1D array containing subplots

#plot data on appropriate axes
sns.barplot(x = 'Hair', y = 'Age', data=plot_1, ci=None, palette=['#0373fc'], ax=axes[0])
sns.barplot(x=plot_2.index, y=plot_2.values, ci=None, palette=['#0373fc'], ax=axes[1])
sns.barplot(x=plot_3.index, y=plot_3.values, ci=None, palette=['#0373fc'], ax=axes[2])

#Add y labels to 2nd and 3rd plots
axes[1].set_ylabel('Number of Male or Female')
axes[2].set_ylabel('Average age')
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I will give things a try with my actual data to see if groupby() allows for what I am trying to  achieve, but I would still like to understand how to achieve the simultaneous display of multiple using `pivot_table()` and also without the use of Seaborn (although I do intent to look into it).  I am just making up the syntax here (and can imagine many variations of this sort), but ideally I would want to be able to do something like `plt.plot(pivot1); plt.plot(pivot2); plt.plot(pivot3); plt.show()`.  Any suggestions insofar as sticking to pivot_table() and  plt.show() ?